# Can't change the color of tab header in Angular2 material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I cant change the color of my tab header in css. Can someone help me? Here's is my code.

```
<md-tab-group>
  <md-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
    <template md-tab-label> {{ tab.title }} </template>
    <template md-tab-content> 
      <md-content> 
        <md-card>
          <md-card-title> {{ tab.cardTitle }} </md-card-title>
          <md-card-content>
            {{ tab.content }} 
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </md-content> 
    </template>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Comment: Maybe also add your "best" css attempt, as the tricks often lay in the details, like typos or so, when it comes to CSS ...

Comment: md-tab-header {
  background: white;
}

.md-tab-header {
  background: white;
}

md-tab-group > .md-tab-header {
  background: white;
}

here it is.

Comment: That was my different attempts. It looks like Angular2 or the browser is not reading my css when i select the class.

Comment: Try `:host .md-tab-header { background: red; }` https://plnkr.co/edit/plYtE7OuLIvGeoInYDVp?p=preview

Comment: It works with :host at the beginning. Thanks a lot @yurzui